# About objectAtIndex's return value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray

```
    NSLog(@" --- object id = %ld --- ", 
          (long) [mp_list objectAtIndex : 0]);     

    target_coordinate_2D = [[mp_list objectAtIndex : 0] coordinate];

    // Some test code here which verifies that target_coordinate_2D   
    // gets assigned a valid "coordinate" value.

    [mapView addAnnotation : [mp_list objectAtIndex : 0]];
```

Consider the above 3 statements :

According to documentation, the NSArray's method "objectAtIndex" should return an object.  My understanding is the value returned is a numeric pointer to the object.

But what I got is :

```
--- object id = 0 ---
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[... addObject:]: attempt to insert nil'
```

My questions are :

1

Why  "object id" is nil ?  Since target_coordinate_2D got assigned a valid value, 
[mp_list objectAtIndex : 0] should indeed be a valid object with a valid "coordinate" 
property.

2

On the last statement, I wish to add the object in mp_list to mapView.  The NS Exception
thrown by the simulator is consistent of the fact that "[mp_list objectAtIndex : 0]" is
indeed nil.  So there must be something I have missed about NSArray.  What should be
done in order to assign an object to an array from another array ?

Hope that somebody knowledgable in this area can help ...

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html

Comment: If you're trying to print the pointer to an object, you should use `%p` as your format specifier and don't cast the object to `(long)`, just leave it alone. In other words use `NSLog(@" --- object id = %p --- ", [mp_list objectAtIndex:0]);`

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I have changed it to %p and now I got "0x0" instead of "0".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like `mp_list` itself is `nil`, which is why `[mp_list objectAtIndex:0]` is returning `nil` (because messaging `nil` returns `nil`).

Comment: @Keven, you are right mp_list is nil.  I must have made a mistake somewhere.  But do you think this is the right way to add an object from an array to another ?  I mean, if mp_list were not nil and has a valid object at index == 0 ...

Comment: @Stanley: Sure, there's nothing wrong with `[someMutableArray addObject:[otherArray objectAtIndex:0]]`, assuming that you really do just want to take the first object in an array and add it to a second array.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Have checked that mp_list is nil all along. On the second statement, target_coordinate_2D got assigned a valid value is just an illusion. It could just be holding a previous value. What is unexpected is the second statement goes without any error. Seems that the nil object has just neglected the "coordinate" message call. My last remaining query would be why target_coordinate_2D wouldn't got overwritten with some other values   as a result ...

Comment: Messaging nil returns nil. Or 0, or NULL, or whatever the equivalent of 0 is in the given type. On some architectures, floating-point return types are garbage, though I think on the modern runtime that's always dealt with. Similarly, struct return values are garbage, though I think recent clang actually fixes that.

Comment: BTW, "garbage" in this case means whatever was in that memory location before. For floating point, it's whatever was in the fp register. For structs, it's whatever was on the stack. So sometimes you'll get 0 values in the struct fields, sometimes you'll get complete garbage. This can make it hard to debug, but this is also why I *believe* recent clang zeroes out the struct's fields before calling the message, such that it will be zero'd if you message `nil`.

Comment: Thanks for the very good analysis.  mp_list was nil out of my own mistake, it was not initialized simply because a line of code was left out.  Agree with you that it was difficult to debug for the reasons mentioned.  Thanks ...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is right, but in your NSLog, you're printing out the object as a long?  From what I know, you can only put objects in NSArray, you can't put primitive types in them.  So it might be something about the data you're putting in your array.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  But the format code for double is %lf.  %ld is for long. ---http://www.dgp.toronto.edu/~ajr/209/notes/printf.html

Comment: Also, thanks for reminding me about the primitive types.  The object in question should be ok in that respect ...

Comment: About printing the object as long, I was just using the fact that objects in Objective-C are actually long integers representing the memory addresses where the objects info are stored.  The printed out values represent those addresses.  The practice is to check whether the address has a value.

Comment: Also, Kevin is right in telling me that I should use "%p" instead of "%ld". Because there is no guarantee that the pointer is of type long. For modern 64bits machines it could well be of type long long (for 64bits integers).